# parameter and item in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having issues passing a value.

this is my attempt:

```
batchP.updateItemNfilter2(JobType.ImportJob, importJobId, item.getID(), item.getNfilter2());
```

in my batch persistence I have:

```
/**
     * updates nfilter2 value
     * @param jobType
     * @param jobID
     * @param itemID
     * @param nfilter2
     */

    public void updateItemNfilter(short idx, JobType jobType, long jobId, long itemID, long n) throws Exception {
        batchSql.updateItemNfilter(idx, getJobItemTableName(jobType, jobId), itemID, n);
    }
```

any idea what i may be doing wrong? is it because i am trying to pass an item and it is expecting a param?

thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? You are not really calling the method you have provided (updateItemNfilter2 -> updateItemNfilter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us what the actual error is, but you are passing four arguments to a method that takes five.

Looks like you are missing the parameter for `short idx`.